# Running Visual Studio for web development without Admin privileges

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, tfs

I've been running Visual Studio as admin for a few years now.  As of today, my user account no longer has admin rights.  Rather, I have a second account that has elevated privileges. The problem I'm running into is that if I run the application now with my second account, all  my TFS mapping, applications settings, history are all tied to my original account. I have web projects that won't load if I'm not admin, and show as locked by another user if I log in with my Admin account.

So, rather than taking the obvious, and lengthy, route of checking in all files and basically getting rid of all TFS mappings from my original account and then maintaining two user accounts, I'm hoping for a way to develop without having to use my admin account.

Is this possible?  Can I develop website (currently the won't load) if I run without admin rights?

Comment: Related: [Running Visual Studio without admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3810834/3357935)

Answer (score -2):

On the start menu Right Click on your visual studio icon.  In the bottom Application Bar that appears, click "Run as Administrator".

Comment: I want to know how to get the functionality I need WITH OUT running as Admin.