# Using Visual studio without installing

Tags: visual-studio

I need to use visual studio without installing because I don't have admin rights. Help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Help me with this Issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Visual Studio without Admin rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011725/can-i-install-visual-studio-without-admin-rights)

Comment: You can install Visual Studio Code, as a user with no admin rights [here's](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows) the link.

Comment: No i need visual studio not vscode

Comment: Ask your sysadmin to install it for you. If he doesn't want to do that, tell your boss that you can't do the job you're supposed to do. That normally helps to get the permissions very quickly.